# Flutter / Dart JSON decode failing on duplicate nested objects

Tags: json, flutter, dart, json-deserialization

In my Flutter app, I'm converting the following JSON:

```
{
  "2023-11-09": [
    {
      "id": 39,
      "name": "Bunion Removal - Edith Davison",
      "placeId": "ChIJwQhUmsO_woARfq8XEsZwfvI",
      "schedule": {
        "id": 9,
        "serviceId": 24,
        "locationDescription": "501 South Buena Vista Street, Burbank, California, 91505",
        "dateTimeStart": "2023-08-28T10:00:00-07:00",
        "dateTimeEnd": "2023-08-28T11:00:00-07:00",
        "recurrence": "RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=TH"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 43,
      "name": "Bunion Removal - Alfredo Mack",
      "placeId": "ChIJwQhUmsO_woARfq8XEsZwfvI",
      "schedule": {
        "id": 9,
        "serviceId": 24,
        "locationDescription": "501 South Buena Vista Street, Burbank, California, 91505",
        "dateTimeStart": "2023-08-28T10:00:00-07:00",
        "dateTimeEnd": "2023-08-28T11:00:00-07:00",
        "recurrence": "RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=TH"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

While deserializing into object classes in Dart/Flutter, everything works fine... I've got an Appointment class that contains a Schedule class. Normally, the JSON decoder works perfectly.

However in this case where there are two appointments with the same schedule, the second instance of the appointment in the Json Map contains a 'schedule' with only its id field (introspected via the debugger), thus causing the deserialization snafu.

I've tried playing around with the == / hashcode functions on the Schedule class - even to the extent of always creating unique values (various means), but to no avail... I still end up with the following exception, but only when multiple appointments have the same schedule:

```
E/flutter (17946): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: Class 'int' has no instance method '[]'.
E/flutter (17946): Receiver: 30
E/flutter (17946): Tried calling: []("id")
E/flutter (17946): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:38:5)
```

Here are the relevant class methods:

```
  factory Appointment.fromJSON(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Appointment (
    id: json['id'],
    name: json['name'],
    placeId: json['placeId'],
    schedule: null != json['schedule'] ? Schedule.fromJSON(json['schedule']) : null
  );
```

and

```
  factory Schedule.fromJSON(dynamic json) => Schedule (
      id: json['id'],
      serviceId: json['serviceId'],
      locationDescription: json['locationDescription'],
      dateTimeStart: json['dateTimeStart'],
      dateTimeEnd: json['dateTimeEnd'],
      recurrence: json['recurrence']
  );
```

Any and all help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The only thing i can sense is wrong is the argument (dynamic json)

Try specifying it as Map<String,dynamic>

```
factory Schedule.fromJSON(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Schedule (
      id: json['id'],
      serviceId: json['serviceId'],
      locationDescription: json['locationDescription'],
      dateTimeStart: json['dateTimeStart'],
      dateTimeEnd: json['dateTimeEnd'],
      recurrence: json['recurrence']
);
```